# drupal_set_message do not work

Tags: php, drupal, checkbox, drupal-7

I have these checkboxes:

```
   $severity_levels = variable_get('severity_levels', array());

      // Declare empty options array
      $severity_options = array();

      // Loop through each severity level and push to options array for form
      foreach (watchdog_severity_levels() as $severity) {
        $severity_options[$severity] = t('@description', array(
          '@description' => drupal_ucfirst($severity),
        ));
      }
    $form['severity']['severity_levels'] = array(
          '#type' => 'checkboxes',
          '#options' => $severity_options,
          '#default_value' => array_values($severity_levels),
      );
```

and i call them and i want when nothing is checked to get out this error message:

```
$severity_levels = variable_get('severity_levels', array());

  foreach ($severity_levels as $level => $selected) {
    if (!$selected) {
      continue;
      $message = 'You must select at least one severity';
      $type = 'error';
      drupal_set_message($message, $type);
      watchdog($type, $message);
    }
```

but it is not work..... where is my fault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not worth the added complexity to try and optimize a loop like this with `continue` statements.

Just set a flag to `FALSE`, then iterate over all the checkboxes and set the flag to `TRUE` if any are checked. After the loop completes, if the flag is still `FALSE`, then trigger the error.

Try this:

```
function yourform_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $checked = FALSE;

  $severity_levels = $form_state['values']['severity_levels'];
  foreach ($severity_levels as $level => $selected) {
    if ($selected) { $checked = TRUE; }
  }

  if ($selected === FALSE) {
    $message = 'You must select at least one severity.';
    $type = 'error';
    drupal_set_message($message, $type);
    watchdog($type, $message);
  }
}
```

Comment: I noticed your original code retrieves the values for $severity_levels from the variables, when it should be obtaining them from the form's submitted values.  I've edited my answer so that it shows an entire Drupal validation function.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the `continue` in the foreach loop. All code under `continue` in the `if` condition will not be executed.

This code can help you further. It basically sets the message when no security levels have been selected.

```
$has_error = null;
foreach ($severity_levels as $level => $selected) {
    if (!$selected) {
        $has_error = $has_error === null || $has_error === true 
            ? true : false;

        continue;
    }

    $has_error = false;
}

if ($has_error) {
    $message = 'You must select at least one severity';
    $type = 'error';

    drupal_set_message($message, $type);
    watchdog($type, $message);
}
```

Comment: Replying with 'it does not work' doesn't help us, please give more info what is not working. Try to add some debug code to help you further ...